# How to interpret a nested inheritance class structure?

Tags: c++, class, multiple-inheritance

I am modifying some C++ code that start with the following code:

```
class AAAA {
public:
    class BBBB : public CCCC {   // CCCC from include CCCC.h
        friend class AAAA;
        typedef ... ;

    public:
        BBBB() {}
        BBBB(AAAA& thething, uint8_t a = 1) {
           init(&thething, a);
        }
        virtual ~BBBB(){}
//...
}
```

However as non-professional C++ programmer, this is very confusing and daunting.

Why would a subclass have its super class as a friend class?

What is the meaning of:

(a) `class BBBB : public CCCC`, and
(b) `BBBB() {}` followed by
(c) `virtual ~BBBB(){}`, in this case?

---

I have already looked at the following SO answers:

- [Structuring classes with multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874180/structuring-classes-with-multiple-inheritance)
- [Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c)

Comment: Are you asking about class nesting? C++ allows that, nothing really unusual about it. Why someone used that depends on the concrete case. Maybe it is not a correct architecture. Or maybe it is, we can't possibly know that without seeing the real code.

Comment: You posted some code that doesn't relate to the inheritance alone, so I assume it's not just that which you find unclear. Could you please highlight what exactly you want an answer to focus on?

Comment: ^ *That* much I understood myself, and the code works. But I don't understand most other parts. Why would a subclass have its super class as a *friend* class? What is the meaning of  (a) `class BBBB : public CCCC`, and (b) `BBBB() {}` followed by (c) `virtual ~BBBB(){}`, in this case?

Comment: ^^ that should be your question instead of "How can I make sense of all this?" which is too broad and unclear

Comment: @not2qubit (a) simple class definition with inheritance, (b) constructor, (c) virtual destructor. There's nothing else here. The question why a nested class has its "owner" class as a friend sounds interesting though. Mistake? Code evolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would look at `BBBB` and `CCCC` by themselves.

```cpp
class BBBB : public CCCC {   // CCCC from include CCCC.h
    friend class AAAA;
    typedef ... ;

public:
    BBBB() {}
    BBBB(AAAA& thething, uint8_t a = 1) {
       init(&thething, a);
    }
    virtual ~BBBB(){}
}
```

`BBBB` is a pretty standard class that derives from `CCCC`. The only unusual thing is the `friend class AAAA`, which allows the methods in `AAAA` to access private (and protected) methods and fields in `BBBB`.

The fact that `BBBB` is nested in `AAAA` means that to use `BBBB`, you'd have to access it with `AAAA::BBBB b;`, and that `BBBB` can access private (and protected) methods and fields in `AAAA`.

> Why would a subclass have its super class as a friend class?
>   What is the meaning of:
>   (a) `class BBBB : public CCCC`, and
>   (b) `BBBB() {}` followed by
>   (c) `virtual ~BBBB(){}`, in this case?

`AAAA` is not the *super class* of `BBBB`, it is the *enclosing class*. See above.

(a) indicates that `BBBB` inherits from `CCCC`. (b) is the default constructor. (c) is the destructor, and for classes using inheritance it is recommended to make destructors `virtual`.